# Going back and forth with methods in Java

Tags: java

I built a tic tac toe game using java but I just have one issue.  I want my code to bounce back and forth from the `validPlayerOneInput` and `validPlayerTwoInput` methods.  As you can see in my main, I'm calling both methods procedurally which be incorrect as it just stops after the method is called.  I want this to keep running until a winner is determined.

How do I do so?

```
import java.util.*;

public class tictactoe {

    private static char board[][] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
    char p1Sym, p2Sym;

    public tictactoe() {
        p1Sym ='X';
        p2Sym = 'O';
        boardFill();
    }

    void boardFill() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j]);  
                System.out.print(" | ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    void validInputPlayerOne() {
        boolean isSet = true;
        int player1Input, player1CorrectedInput;
        System.out.println("Player 1, enter a number between 1-9: ");

        Scanner player1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        player1Input = player1.nextInt();

        Scanner correctedInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(player1Input < 1 || player1Input >= 10) {
            System.out.println("This isn't a number between 1-9, try again: ");
            player1CorrectedInput = correctedInput.nextInt();
            player1Input = player1CorrectedInput;
        }   

        // or
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == player1Input) {
                    // set new value
                    board[i][j] = p1Sym;
                    // set
                    isSet = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!isSet) {
            System.out.println("not found");
        }   
    }

    void validInputPlayerTwo() {
        boolean isSet = true;
        int player2Input, player2CorrectedInput;
        System.out.println("Player 2, enter a number between 1-9: ");

        Scanner player2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        player2Input = player2.nextInt();

        Scanner correctedInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(player2Input < 1 || player2Input >= 10) {
            System.out.println("This isn't a number between 1-9, try again: ");
            player2CorrectedInput = correctedInput.nextInt();
            player2Input = player2CorrectedInput;
        }   

        // or
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == player2Input){

                    board[i][j] = p2Sym;

                    isSet = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!isSet) {
            System.out.println("not found");
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tictactoe t = new tictactoe();      

        t.validInputPlayerOne();
        t.boardFill();
        t.validInputPlayerTwo();
        t.boardFill();              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
int turn = 0;
while (t.noWinner()) {
  if (turn % 2 == 0) t.validInputPlayerOne();
  else t.validInputPlayerTwo();
  t.boardFill();
  turn += 1;
}
```

Of course, now you have to actually write the `noWinner` function.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question directly, you could have a boolean that toggles on each move:

```
boolean firstPlayer = true;
while (t.gameIsNotFinished()) {
    if (firstPlayer)
        t.validInputPlayerOne();
    else
        t.validInputPlayerTwo();
    firstPlayer = !firstPlayer;
}
```

However you have a lot of other issues with your code that you need to address. For example if a player enters an invalid value then it goes to the next player rather than asking for them to reenter the value.

You should also try to have a single `validInputPlayer` method that works for both players with the `firstPlayer` variable passed in. At the moment you have a lot of repeated code in those methods.